# FXAA Shader turns image upside-down

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl, antialiasing

I'm trying to use an [existing FXAA shader](http://www.geeks3d.com/20110405/fxaa-fast-approximate-anti-aliasing-demo-glsl-opengl-test-radeon-geforce/3/) for anti-aliasing, which works, but when I try to run it, the filtered image is upside-down (vertically flipped)

```
[Vertex_Shader]
varying vec4 posPos;
uniform float FXAA_SUBPIX_SHIFT = 1.0/4.0;
uniform float rt_w; // GeeXLab built-in
uniform float rt_h; // GeeXLab built-in

void main(void)
{
  gl_Position = ftransform();
  gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
  vec2 rcpFrame = vec2(1.0/rt_w, 1.0/rt_h);
  posPos.xy = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy;
  posPos.zw = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy - 
                  (rcpFrame * (0.5 + FXAA_SUBPIX_SHIFT));
}

[Pixel_Shader]
#version 120
uniform sampler2D tex0; // 0
uniform float vx_offset;
uniform float rt_w; // GeeXLab built-in
uniform float rt_h; // GeeXLab built-in
uniform float FXAA_SPAN_MAX = 8.0;
uniform float FXAA_REDUCE_MUL = 1.0/8.0;
varying vec4 posPos;

#define FxaaInt2 ivec2
#define FxaaFloat2 vec2
#define FxaaTexLod0(t, p) texture2DLod(t, p, 0.0)
#define FxaaTexOff(t, p, o, r) texture2DLodOffset(t, p, 0.0, o)

vec3 FxaaPixelShader( 
  vec4 posPos, // Output of FxaaVertexShader interpolated across screen.
  sampler2D tex, // Input texture.
  vec2 rcpFrame) // Constant {1.0/frameWidth, 1.0/frameHeight}.
{   
/*---------------------------------------------------------*/
    #define FXAA_REDUCE_MIN   (1.0/128.0)
    //#define FXAA_REDUCE_MUL   (1.0/8.0)
    //#define FXAA_SPAN_MAX     8.0
/*---------------------------------------------------------*/
    vec3 rgbNW = FxaaTexLod0(tex, posPos.zw).xyz;
    vec3 rgbNE = FxaaTexOff(tex, posPos.zw, FxaaInt2(1,0), rcpFrame.xy).xyz;
    vec3 rgbSW = FxaaTexOff(tex, posPos.zw, FxaaInt2(0,1), rcpFrame.xy).xyz;
    vec3 rgbSE = FxaaTexOff(tex, posPos.zw, FxaaInt2(1,1), rcpFrame.xy).xyz;
    vec3 rgbM  = FxaaTexLod0(tex, posPos.xy).xyz;
/*---------------------------------------------------------*/
    vec3 luma = vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114);
    float lumaNW = dot(rgbNW, luma);
    float lumaNE = dot(rgbNE, luma);
    float lumaSW = dot(rgbSW, luma);
    float lumaSE = dot(rgbSE, luma);
    float lumaM  = dot(rgbM,  luma);
/*---------------------------------------------------------*/
    float lumaMin = min(lumaM, min(min(lumaNW, lumaNE), min(lumaSW, lumaSE)));
    float lumaMax = max(lumaM, max(max(lumaNW, lumaNE), max(lumaSW, lumaSE)));
/*---------------------------------------------------------*/
    vec2 dir; 
    dir.x = -((lumaNW + lumaNE) - (lumaSW + lumaSE));
    dir.y =  ((lumaNW + lumaSW) - (lumaNE + lumaSE));
/*---------------------------------------------------------*/
    float dirReduce = max(
        (lumaNW + lumaNE + lumaSW + lumaSE) * (0.25 * FXAA_REDUCE_MUL),
        FXAA_REDUCE_MIN);
    float rcpDirMin = 1.0/(min(abs(dir.x), abs(dir.y)) + dirReduce);
    dir = min(FxaaFloat2( FXAA_SPAN_MAX,  FXAA_SPAN_MAX), 
          max(FxaaFloat2(-FXAA_SPAN_MAX, -FXAA_SPAN_MAX), 
          dir * rcpDirMin)) * rcpFrame.xy;
/*--------------------------------------------------------*/
    vec3 rgbA = (1.0/2.0) * (
        FxaaTexLod0(tex, posPos.xy + dir * (1.0/3.0 - 0.5)).xyz +
        FxaaTexLod0(tex, posPos.xy + dir * (2.0/3.0 - 0.5)).xyz);
    vec3 rgbB = rgbA * (1.0/2.0) + (1.0/4.0) * (
        FxaaTexLod0(tex, posPos.xy + dir * (0.0/3.0 - 0.5)).xyz +
        FxaaTexLod0(tex, posPos.xy + dir * (3.0/3.0 - 0.5)).xyz);
    float lumaB = dot(rgbB, luma);
    if((lumaB < lumaMin) || (lumaB > lumaMax)) return rgbA;
    return rgbB; }

vec4 PostFX(sampler2D tex, vec2 uv, float time)
{
  vec4 c = vec4(0.0);
  vec2 rcpFrame = vec2(1.0/rt_w, 1.0/rt_h);
  c.rgb = FxaaPixelShader(posPos, tex, rcpFrame);
  //c.rgb = 1.0 - texture2D(tex, posPos.xy).rgb;
  c.a = 1.0;
  return c;
}

void main() 
{ 
  vec2 uv = gl_TexCoord[0].st;
  gl_FragColor = PostFX(tex0, uv, 0.0);
}
```

I'm still new to shaders - how can I modify this shader so the filtered image is displayed the correct way up?

Answer (score -1):

```
gl_FragColor = PostFX(tex0, vec2(uv.x, 1.0 - uv.y), 0.0);
```

Comment: Single line answers rarely make good answers. What is this line of code doing and why is it the solution? We try to help the user and not just fix the issues they have :)

Comment: The reason is the uv coordinate of OpenGL, which is located at downleft. The raw texture data's first pixel is at (0, 0), which is located at topleft.So you have to flip the y of uv to sample the right pixel from the texture